# Can I mutate any element of an array by making it equal to any integer variable declared but not initialized?

Tags: c, arrays

Code:

```
         #include<stdio.h>
         #include<conio.h>
         int main()
         {
                 int a, b, c, d,t;
                 int arr[8]={8,6,5,6,7,8,7,8};
                 int arr_foo[8]={6,7,8,4,8,4,2,7};
                 printf("the first array is\n");
                 for(a=0; a<8; a++)
                 {
                            printf("%d %s", arr[a], ",");
                 }
                 printf("\n");
                 printf("the second array is\n");
                 for(a=0; a<8; a++)
                 {
                            printf("%d %s", arr_foo[a], ",");
                 }
                 printf("\n");
                 for(a=0; a<8; a++)
                 {
                          for(b=a+1; b<8; b++)
                          {
                                     if(arr[a]==arr[b])
                                     {
                                             arr[b]=t;
                                     }
                          }
                          if(arr[a] != t)
                          {
                                 c=0;
                                 for(d=0; d<8; d++)
                                 {
                                       if(arr[a]==arr_foo[d])
                                       {
                                             c++;
                                       }
                                 }
                                 printf("%d %s %d %s\n", arr[a], "found", c, "times");
                   }//end if
           }//end for
           getch();
           return 0;
        }//end main
```

The code contains two arrays and searches if the elements of first array is present in 2nd array .If it is, the how many times?
             I want to know that is it reasonable to put `arr[b]=t` where `t` is any integer variable

Comment: The title's answer is yes. But I am not sure how the title is related to the code in the question.

Comment: `printf("%d %s", arr[a], ",");` -> `printf("%d, ", arr[a]);`

Comment: `t` might overlap with the elements already.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  Yes.  But you'll get a junk value.

Long answer (and much better from  Eric Postpischil):

> The behavior is not defined by the C standard. Per C 2011 (N1570)
>   6.3.2.1 2: “If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class
>   (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not
>   declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been
>   performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.”

Comment: The behavior is not defined by the C standard. Per C 2011 (N1570) 6.3.2.1 2: “If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.”

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you use an uninitialized object, the behavior is not defined by the C 2011 standard:

> If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined.

In C 1999, the behavior was partially defined. Using an uninitialized value would merely give you an indeterminate value. As long as that value was not a trap representation, the code would execute as if some the object had been initialized to some unspecified value.

Most implementations will provide the C 1999 behavior and will not have trap representations for `int`. But there is at least one implementation that may trap if you use an uninitialized value (which is the reason that language was added to the C 2011 standard). So, if you want to rely only on the C 2011 standard, you may not use uninitialized objects of automatic storage duration (unless you take their addresses).